# Translation of Qt buttons not working with QTranslator

Tags: python, pyqt5, localization, qtranslator

Usually I do translate my Python applications with GNU gettext. But I realized that standard elements (e.g. `QDialogButtonBox.Yes`) in a Qt GUI are not translated.

So I found examples with `QTranslator`. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. I would expect that Qt handles the translation itself and realize which locale is currently activate. I would expect a simple switch like `.use_current_local()`.

I couldn't find such an Qt option so I tried the `QTranslator` examples without understanding them in all details. The example here does run without errors but the buttons are not translated and looking like this.

I tried three variants for the value of the locale variable: explicit `de_DE.UTF8`, `QLocale.system().name` (returns `de_DE`) and `qt_de_DE`. The latter seems wired but comes from an real world example which I don't understand.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialogButtonBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTranslator, QLocale, QLibraryInfo


def get_translator():
    translator = QTranslator()

    # Variant 1
    loc = QLocale.system().name()

    # Variant 2
    # loc = 'de_DE.utf-8',  # qt_%s' % locale,

    # Variant 3
    # loc = 'qt_de_DE',

    print(f'{loc=}')  # <-- de_DE

    translator.load(
        loc,
        QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)
    )

    return translator


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    t = get_translator()
    app.installTranslator(t)

    buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(
        QDialogButtonBox.Ok
        | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        | QDialogButtonBox.Yes
        | QDialogButtonBox.No
    )

    buttonBox.show()
    app.exec()
```

Please note I'm not interested to use Qt to replace my GNU gettext setup. I just want to have the standard Qt elements translated also. All other strings I set myself are still translated via GNU gettext.

I do use Debian 12 here. The `qttranslations5-l10n` package is installed. Other Qt applications (e.g. `backintime-qt`) do work and translate standard GUI elements like buttons without problems.

Comment: If the Qt translation files are installed correctly on your system, "Variant 3" will work. Thus, if I add the line `loc = f'qt_{QLocale(QLocale.German).name()}'` to your example, the button-box shows "Ja", "Nein", "OK", "Abbrechen". On my system, the `load` arguments evaluate to `qt_de_DE` and `/usr/share/qt/translations`, which Qt resolves to the translation file `/usr/share/qt/translations/qt_de.qm`. I suggest you check the corresponding location on your system to see if the relevant files exist.

Comment: PS: if you're using an IDE, make sure you test your example in a normal terminal as well (i.e. by running it directly with python).

Comment: This file exists in the system: `/usr/share/qt5/translations/qt_de.qm` but `strace` tells me that my application try to find the files in `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/translations`.

Comment: I have now confirmed the problem by installing PyQt5 via pip in a venv. For a work-around, and an expalanation of the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by a bug (see below) in the [PyQt5 PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/). This package installs a local copy of Qt5 which includes invalid translation files. The specific issue is that the *qt_xx.qm* file depends on several other translation files, and if any one of them is missing, `QTranslator.load()` will fail.

A temporary work-around is to copy/link the missing translation files from your system qt5 installation to your local pip installation, like this:

```
cp /usr/share/qt5/translations/qtscript_*.qm ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/translations
```

Note that, ironically, it doesn't actually matter what the contents of these files are, since PyQt5 has never provided the QtScript module (which Qt has long-since deprecated anyway).

---

The bug is revealed by decompiling the *qt_xx.qm* file, like so:

```
lconvert /usr/share/qt/translations/qt_de.qm
```

which gives:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="de">
<dependencies>
<dependency catalog="qtbase_de"/>
<dependency catalog="qtscript_de"/>
<dependency catalog="qtmultimedia_de"/>
<dependency catalog="qtxmlpatterns_de"/>
</dependencies>
</TS>
```

The relevant translations are actually provided by the *qtbase_de* file, but because the PyQt5 PyPI package does not include the *qtscript_de* file, `QTranslator` bails out of the entire load operation!

**UPDATE**:

I [reported the bug on the pyqt mailing-list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2023-June/045353.html), and the author has now fixed the underlying issue. However, it appears the PyPI packages won't be updated until a new version of PyQt5 is released, so until then, the above work-around will still be needed.